# How to print sparse matrix in matrix market format, but using 0-index

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I want to use R's Matrix library's writeMM to write a sparse matrix to external file in matrix market format.
see:  https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/Matrix/html/externalFormats.html

matrix

```
4 0
2 4


library(Matrix)
writeMM(matrix, "./outfile.tsv")
```

outfile.tsv:

```
#rowindex #columnindex #value

1 1 4
2 1 2
2 2 4
```

However, I want the printed indices in the output file to be effectively 0 indexed, in contrast to the default in R which is 1-indexed. i.e. I want to subtract 1 from every row and column index that is printed.

How can I do that while using as much of pre-existing functionality as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `reshape2`:

```
m <- matrix(c(4,2,3,4), ncol = 2);

# Reshape
library(reshape2);
m.long <- melt(m);

# 0-based indices
m.long[, 1:2] <- m.long[, 1:2] - 1;

# Optionally sort
m.long <- m.long[order(m.long[, 1],  m.long[, 2]) ,]
print(m.long);
  Var1 Var2 value
1    0    0     4
3    0    1     3
2    1    0     2
4    1    1     4
```

Comment: hm I guess my question wasn't explicit. 1) my matrix is sparse so the printing should ignore the zeros. 2) I'm printing my matrix to a .tsv file, in .tsv format, I don't care about creating an object in that format itself.  writeMM handles that, but does so with the 1-index. I guess theoretically I could implement what you did and write a print function to ignore the zeros. Just prefer something more elegant.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. 1. Your matrix contains no zeros. If you only want to print non-zero matrix entries, you can simply filter entries `m.long[m.long$value > 0, ]`. 2. My `print` statements are only there to show the output. Obviously you can write the object to a tab-separated file. My solution consists of one call to `melt` and a shift in indices numbering  (including some optional formatting lines).  I don't know how much more "elegant" or concise you'd like to be.

Comment: cool, I think this works then, after recasting from sparse matrix into full matrix and filtering out zeros!  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `summary` function for a `Matrix` object returns a dataframe with columns `i`, `j`, and `x`. There is one row for each nonzero entry. Just subtract 1 from columns `i` and `j` and you're good to go -- plus, you haven't wasted a shit-ton of memory.

UPDATE:

This doesn't work for all sparse matrices from the `Matrix` package, but it should work if you do `summary(as(my_mat, "dgTMatrix"))`.